# inserting default database entry on onCreate method

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

here is my database helper class:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Database", "DATABASE CREATE");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                    + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS
                    + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);"

            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Database", "DATABASE CREATE");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }
```

is there any way insert a default database entries when you first opened the application. like  its inside the onCreate/onUpgrade method?

Comment: Did you mean to say that `db.qxecSQL()` statements should be executed on each and every start of the application ?

Comment: yes but i only know how to use db.insert(); not db.qxecSQL(); is it like  mysql_query(); in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File dbFolder=new File("/data/data/yourpackagename/databases/");
            if(!dbFolder.exists())
            {
                dbFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            File dbFile = new File("/data/data/yourpackagename/databases/"+"dbfilename");
            if(!dbFile.exists() || dbFile.length()<=0)
            {
                dbFile.createNewFile();

                InputStream fIn=context.getAssets().open("QuizDB.jpeg");
                byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
                FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
                int c=fIn.read(buffer);
                while (c!=-1)
                {
                    fout.write(buffer);
                    c=fIn.read(buffer);
                }
                fout.close();
```

Keep your database ready file in assets and write the above code after splash screen.
I have done the same for my quiz app. In this i had question and answer in hand already. 
so i used above code. QuizDB.jpeg is my database file name.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query("QuizTable1", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if( c.moveToNext() )
    {
      c.getString(0);
    }
```

Above code to read database.
Note::QuizTable1 is the table I created in my database.

Comment: this is the most efficient answer i have come across but i don't know how to use buffer reader in java.

Comment: U can refer java docs at Oracle site but why do u need to know buffer for this? By using above code you can create database.

Comment: To read database I have edited the post. plz refer it. If this answer is helpful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is plugin available for Creating and inserting data manually on sqlite data base.

If you are using mozilla firefox than use this adons

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

After Installing to open it on mozilla firefox `Tools->SQLite Manager->And Create Database`

Install it and create database manually and insert record manually from there.After creating database you can put data base with `.sqlite`  extension on Asset Folder.

After putting on asset folder you can read [This Tutorial](http://mobile-development-tutorial.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-external-sqlite-database.html) for reading records from external database                                                                 `[I.E from .sqlite file put on asset folder]`

Answer (score 1):

Just add whatever `insert` calls you want to your `onCreate()` after creating the table.

E.g.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS
                + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);"

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_NAME, "name");
cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, "burning");
db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Comment: is it ok if i put like 60 default entries? i know it'll be inefficient but i wanna ask anyway..

Comment: @ChristianBurgos Shouldn't be a problem. `onCreate()` already runs in a database transaction so the time waiting for I/O is minimized.

Comment: will this be saved even if i put some extra contents on the database?

Answer (score 0):

what you mean by default database entries . you can add **`DEFAULT value`** after column .please elaborate your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have your default database saved in a file, then load it in your onCreate().

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible. Insert default values inside onCreate Method of your helper class.

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Database", "DATABASE CREATE");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                    + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS
                    + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);"

            );

            SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "name");
        values.put(KEY_HOTNESS, "hotness");

        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();

        }
```

Comment: where is the problem ?

Comment: Even if you get the reference of the db from methods other than onCreate(), its still the same variable of the same SQLiteOpenHelper class. :)

Comment: Ah, didn't see the `getWritableDatabase()` call at first due to the indentation. Sry. But that's still not necessary as `db` is already open for writing.